# python: extract value from one dataframe and insert into another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The issue is part of a much larger and more complex code but I have narrowed down the minimum reproducible behavior to the following

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'cola':[1,2,3], 'colb':['a','b','c']})

selected = df1[df1['cola'] == 1]

tempDf = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[selected['cola']], 'col2': [10]})
```

my expected output is a two column df with the values of `1` and `10`. What I am getting is a two column df where the first column is `0    1 Name: cola, dtype: int64` and the second column is `10`. How can I edit this code to only get the column value and what is causing this behavior?

Comment: `tempDf = pd.DataFrame({'col1':selected['cola'], 'col2': [10]})` get rid of extra squared bracket. `selected['cola']` itself is 1D values which you are putting inside a list that makes it include the indices as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are passing is a list of 1D values by `[selected['cola']]` for `col1`, if you remove the enclosing squared bracket, you'll get the expected output:

```py
tempDf = pd.DataFrame({'col1':selected['cola'], 'col2': [10]})
# tempDf
   col1  col2
0     1    10

# for reference
# print([selected['cola']])
# [0    1
# Name: cola, dtype: int64]
```